# Merge hot source1 with a cold source2

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

source1 emits A,B,C,D etc and never completes

source2 emit 1,2 and completes

I want to merge to A1, B2, C1, D2 etc

**update**

my initial attemp was to `Zip` and `Repeat` as suggested from `Theodor` however this creates a lock cause source2 generation is expensive.

Last comment from `Enigmativity` addresses that problem

```
source1.Zip(source2.ToEnumerable().ToArray().Repeat())
```

Comment: Something like `source1.Zip(source2.Repeat())`?

Comment: What do you understand that "hot" and "cold" observables mean?

Comment: @th
 I do not want to repeat source2 if possible

Comment: @Enigmativity a cold gives back the same items any time i subsbribe

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - But you appear to be repeating it. Are you saying you don't want repeated subscriptions to it?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes subscribing again is unwanted

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - Then `source1.Zip(source2.ToEnumerable().ToArray().Repeat())`.

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris - if you don't care about the ordering of the output, then `from s2 in source2 from s1 in source1 select (s1 ,s2)"` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to repeat `source2` indefinitely and you say that it is cold (in the sense that it produces the same set of values each time, and generally in the same sort of cadence) and it is expensive, we want to turn the `IObservable<T>` into a `T[]` to ensure it's computed once and only once.

```
var array = source2.ToEnumerable().ToArray();
var output = source1.Zip(array.Repeat(), (x, y) => (x, y));
```

Comment: maybe u can clarify a bit about the cold definition I gave and also updated my post to clarify my initial research and problems further. Thsnks for the input!

Comment: I find that hot and cold get very confused in the Rx world. I tend to look at it that an observable is cold if it inexpensively gives the same values for every subscription, it's cold. If it gives different values to different subscribers, or at different times, or at great expense then these things make the observable hotter and hotter means you have to be more thoughtful about how you use the observable.

Comment: Enigmativity I think that a sequence that emits the same values to all concurrent subscribers is probably hot, not cold!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - And how does that differentiation help in writing queries?

Comment: Enigmativity this is a broad philosophical question that I would have a hard time answering, even if I was not restricted by the 500-chars limit per comment. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, and that's why I think there's such confusion with hot versus cold.

Comment: Enigmativity I think that you should fix your initial comment, because it contributes to this confusion. The descriptions of hot and cold sequences are reversed!

Comment: Btw instead of `var array = source2.ToEnumerable().ToArray();` I would suggest `var array = await source2.ToArray();` as an improvement, to avoid blocking the current thread.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the desirable marble diagram is like this:

```
Source1: +--------A-------B-------C--------D-------|
Source2: +----1--------------2--------|
Merged:  +--------A1---------B2-------C1---D2------|
```

Here is a `ZipWithRepeated` operator having this behavior:

```
static IObservable<(TFirst First, TSecond Second)> ZipWithRepeated<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this IObservable<TFirst> first, IObservable<TSecond> second)
{
    return second.Replay(replayed => first.ToAsyncEnumerable()
        .Zip(replayed.ToAsyncEnumerable().Repeat())
        .ToObservable());
}
```

Usage example:

```
var merged = source1.ZipWithRepeated(source2);
```

This solution requires a dependency to the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) and [System.Interactive.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) packages, because both sequences are converted to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`s before the zipping.

---

**Alternative**: Instead of relying on the Rx `Replay` operator for the buffering of the source2 sequence, a more efficient solution would be to do the buffering after the conversion from observable to async-enumerable. AFAICS there is no built-in support for replaying/[memoizing](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_Experimental_ExperimentalEnumerable_Memoize__1.htm) `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`s in the official Rx/Ix libraries, but creating a custom `Repeat` operator with embedded buffering is not very difficult. Below is an alternative implementation of the `ZipWithRepeated` operator, which is based on this idea:

```
static IObservable<(TFirst First, TSecond Second)> ZipWithRepeated<TFirst, TSecond>(
    this IObservable<TFirst> first, IObservable<TSecond> second)
{
    return first.ToAsyncEnumerable()
        .Zip(second.ToAsyncEnumerable().RepeatBuffered())
        .ToObservable();
}

private async static IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> RepeatBuffered<TSource>(
    this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var buffer = new List<TSource>();
    await foreach (var item in source
        .WithCancellation(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        buffer.Add(item); yield return item;
    }
    while (true) foreach (var item in buffer) yield return item;
}
```

This implementation does not depend on the System.Interactive.Async package, but only on the System.Linq.Async package.

Comment: I get the feeling that this operator is preferable, canoot guess exactly your motivation though. Care to alab on it a bit?

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris the assumption is that you want to start receiving merged pairs as soon as both sequences have emitted a value, not when the source2 sequence has completed. If you are OK with waiting for the completion of the source2, then Enignativity's solution is simpler and more efficient. My suggestion is slightly inefficient because the elements of the source2 sequence are buffered two times. One time by the `Replay` operator, and another one by the `replayed.ToAsyncEnumerable()`.

Comment: is there a version that compiles in netstanrd2.0?

Comment: @ApostolisBekiaris the System.Interactive.Async package is also required, because it contains the `Repeat` operator for async-enumerable sequences. I just tested that it compiles in a class library with `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`.